# Incorrect loading of a .laz file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, laz

I would like to open a .laz file in QGIS. This is probably not loaded completely. For example, no statistics are shown to me in the layer properties. Also, no ept.json file is created and the ept-data folder contains only about 10 files. However, the .laz file is several gigabytes in size and contains about 250 million points. It loads slowly until about 50% and then finishes the task.

I was able to load another .laz file, which is just under 1 gb in size, without any problems.

Can QGIS not open a file that is too big or do I have to take care of something so that the file is loaded correctly? Or is the file faulty? However, certain attributes are displayed in the layer properties. That is why I do not assume that the file is damaged.
Do I have to use the LAZtool somehow?